# select different image for canvas background

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need to know how can I change the image background in canvas to draw what is needed in the selected image?

I use this script [William malone canvas](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/)
 and I can save the image in DB...the only thing I don't figure is how can I change the background..

EDITED--
My question is how can I change the background image in canvas WITHOUT reload the page...per example with a select list or checkbox or radio button

like this but need to change without reload the page

[image: pies] 
[image: face]

Comment: I want u give an answer to me..

Comment: Hi @MagicJuly, thank you for your support the problem is in this part : `outlineImage.src = "imagenes/cara.png";` not allow me to change the image...always said me prepareCanvas is not defined....inside of `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/drawing-app-with-bucket.js"></script>`

Comment: and when I clicked into the other image to change it show me this error `ReferenceError: outlineImage is not defined`...sorry for my late respond but I am not in my home until today

Answer (score -1):

change the image background is very simple,you just need to write a function and do this:

```
outlineImage.src = "your image src";
```

then background image will changed! You may have a try.

---

Is this you wanted?

[image: make a select list]

[image: change selected option to change background]

You should load needed js files before that function,and be sure that js file is avaliable,especially html5-canvas-drawing-app.js,It's the core function,prepareCanvas and outlineImage are defined in this file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>HTML5 Create HTML5 Canvas JavaScript Drawing App Example</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="canvasDiv"></div>

    <!--src link write in attribute name or id,I suggest that-->
    <select id="changeSrc">
        <option name="images/1.png">Bg1</option>
        <option name="images/2.png">Bg2</option>
    </select>

    <!-- Load js Files -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="html5-canvas-drawing-app.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
         prepareCanvas();
    });

    $("#changeSrc").change(function(){
      var src=$(this).children(':selected').attr('name');    //get selected option's name
      outlineImage.src=src;                                  //change background!
    });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

If it doesn't work yet,I can write an example send to you.

Comment: that I can do it....my question is how can I change the background image in canvas WITHOUT reload the page...per example with a select list or checkbox or radio button

Comment: Hi @MagicJuly, yes that is the function I am looking for...but I have errors when I tried to add your code...1-src is not defined, 2-prepareCanvas is not defined and 3-outlineImage is not defined..  can you please guide me how can I added into the script   Best regards!