# Add image to canvas with select option or with upload and draw it

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

can you help me with this? I am searching for how can add images with a upload or with existing images with select button, then draw in the image and for last save it into DB like a rute of the image is (ex. images/canvas/draw1.jpg or .png)

I follow this two tutorials...but I am not know how finish it

[select-diferent-image-for-canvas-background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25003499/select-diferent-image-for-canvas-background)

[dynamically-add-image-to-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944382/dynamically-add-image-to-canvas)

Comment: You're asking too much for a Stackoverflow question.  SO questions should be focused on a specific problem rather than your broad question about (1) How to upload an image, (2) How to edit the image, (3) how to save the edited image to a database.  If you have a specific question about your code, then SO would be the right place.

Comment: @markE, Hi, it is true...sorry I think I will keep with the first one (select-diferent-image-for-canvas-background) because is the most complete script and is closer to what I need...I hope somebody fix it...because I am still like the user how asked without clue

Answer (score 0):

**This example lets your user drag an image from their desktop onto the background canvas:**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("bk");
var bkctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// dropzone event handlers
var dropzone;
dropzone = document.getElementById("dropzone");
dropzone.addEventListener("dragenter", dragenter, false);
dropzone.addEventListener("dragover", dragover, false);
dropzone.addEventListener("drop", drop, false);

//
function dragenter(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  //

function dragover(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}

//
function drop(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  var dt = e.dataTransfer;
  var files = dt.files;

  handleFiles(files);
}

//
function handleFiles(files) {

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

      // get the next file that the user selected
      var file = files[i];
      var imageType = /image.*/;

      // don't try to process non-images
      if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {
        continue;
      }

      // a seed img element for the FileReader
      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.classList.add("obj");
      img.file = file;

      // get an image file from the user
      // this uses drag/drop, but you could substitute file-browsing
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (function(aImg) {
        return function(e) {
          aImg.onload = function() {
              // draw the aImg onto the canvas
              bkctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
              bkctx.drawImage(aImg, 0, 0);
            }
            // e.target.result is a dataURL for the image
          aImg.src = e.target.result;
        };
      })(img);
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    } // end for

  } // end handleFiles
```

```css
body {
  background-color: ivory;
}
#dropzone {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Drag an image from desktop to blue dropzone.</h4>
<div id="dropzone" width=300 height=300>
  <canvas id="bk" width=300 height=300></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you but I think is more complete the version of William Malone...I just need to know how select the image in the select input to show inside of canvas the selected image and then draw it with those crayons or pilots..

Comment: You asked about letting the user alter the background--that's what I answered.  If you want to integrate William Malone's drawing code then that's beyond the scope of a stackoverflow question.  May I suggest you try to integrate this yourself and ask another question if you have more specific questions about your own code...

Comment: I asked the form to how can add images with a upload or with existing images with select button, then draw in the image and for last save it into DB like a rute of the image is (ex. images/canvas/draw1.jpg or .png)...you give me the drag but I need the part of draw over that image and for last save it...so I told you that the most complete script is that with the william malone script...just is missed the part of select image with the select input and then save it, but thank you for your support

Comment: I put 2 canvases overlaying exactly.  The dragged background image displays what the user drags to the background canvas (bk).  I put the top canvas there for you to code William Malone's sketching app. Do `bkctx.getImageData` to grab the background image pixels and then apply Malone's techniques on the top canvas. But, coding the Malone solution for you is beyond the scope of an SO question+answer Good luck with your project & come back if you have problems with your own code!